# How to find current thread's max stack size in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

How can I find current thread's maximum stack size?

I am getting a stack overflow exception while executing a function from MMC UI but not from Powershell (command-line/console). So I am kind of guessing its something to do with the default stack size allocated in UI thread to that of in Powershell (command line/console).

So how to find current thread's maximum stack size?

I know ideally one doesn't need to know these or set these, but looks like its related to stack size as it works from console/Powershell(command-line app) not from UI.

The below thread is kind of related, but it doesn't answer my question; it probably gives some guidelines:

[Maximum Thread Stack Size .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507574/maximum-thread-stack-size-net)

To get more details about the actual problem:

[StackOverFlowException: Is it programming error (recursion) or not enough maximum default stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027955/stackoverflowexception-is-it-programming-error-recursion-or-not-enough-maximu)

Answer (score 6):

From Windows 8, there is the [GetCurrentThreadStackLimits()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706789.aspx) function. You can use it from C# via PInvoke like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(out uint lowLimit, out uint highLimit);

uint low;
uint high;

GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(out low, out high);
var size = (high - low) / 1024; // in KB
```

On my machine, this yields 1MB in a console application, 256KB in a web application (IIS).

Answer (score 2):

Getting this information is a real PITA actually:

1. Get the thread ID using [GetCurrentThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683183%28VS.85%29.aspx)
2. Use [OpenThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684335%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the thread
3. Now use [NtQueryInformationThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get information about the thread. You'll use `ThreadBasicInformation` as `THREADINFOCLASS` to get a `THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure. You now have the `TebBaseAddress` parameter that is the address of the *Thread Environment Block*.
4. Read in process memory at the `TebBaseAddress` address.
5. Within the *Thread Environment Block* (TEB), you have access to the `StackLimit` property which is the value you're looking for.

From step 3, it's undocumented. That's why I do not recommend retrieving this information.